# Autoencoder loss is not decreasing (and starts very high)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have the following function which is supposed to autoencode my data.

My data can be thought of as an image of length 100, width 2, and it has 2 channels (100, 2, 2)

```
def construct_ae(input_shape):
    encoder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, input_shape, name='x')
    with tf.variable_scope("encoder"):
        flattened = tf.layers.flatten(encoder_input)
        e_fc_1 = tf.layers.dense(flattened, units=150, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        encoded = tf.layers.dense(e_fc_1, units=75, activation=None)

    with tf.variable_scope("decoder"):
        d_fc_1 = tf.layers.dense(encoded, 150, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        d_fc_2 = tf.layers.dense(d_fc_1, 400, activation=None)
        decoded = tf.reshape(d_fc_2, input_shape)

    with tf.variable_scope('training'):
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=encoder_input, predictions=decoded)
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
        return optimizer
```

I'm running into the issue where my cost is on the order of 1.1e9, and it's not decreasing over time

[image: cost over time]

I visualized the gradients (removed the code because it would just clutter things) and I think something is wrong there? But I'm not sure

[image]

**Questions**

1) Does anything in the construction of the network look incorrect?

2) Does the data need to be normalized between 0-1?

3) I hit NaNs sometimes when I try increasing the learning rate to 1. Is that indicative of anything?

4) I think I should probably use a CNN but I ran into the same issues so I thought I'd move to an FC since it's likely easier to debug.

5) I imagine I'm using the wrong loss function but I can't really find any papers regarding the right loss to use. If anyone can direct me to one I'd be very appreciative

Answer (score 2):

1. Given that this is a plain autoencoder and not a convolutional one, you shouldn't expect good (low) error rates.
2. Normalizing does get you faster convergence. However given that your final layer does not have an activation function that enforces a range on the output, it shouldn't be a problem. However, do try normalizing your data to [0,1] and then using a sigmoid activation in your last decoder layer.
3. A very high learning rate may get you stuck in an optimization loop and/or get you too far from any local minima, thus leading to extremely high error rates.
4. Most blogs (like Keras) use 'binary_crossentropy' as their loss function, but MSE isn't "wrong"

As far as the high starting error is concerned; it all depends on your parameters' initialization. A good initialization technique gets you starting errors that are not too far from a desired minima. However, the default random or zeros-based initialization almost always leads to such scenarios.

Comment: 1) I got similar error rates on a convolutional autoencoder which is why I switched to a standard one (I thought it would be easier to debug). 2) I'm essentially trying to reconstruct the original image so normalizing to [0, 1] would be a problem (the original values are essentially unbounded).

I suppose I assume something is wrong because it looks like it learns a little then just bounces around

Comment: "the original values are essentially unbounded": this is not the case. All pixel values are in the range [0, 255], so you can normalize them accordingly.

Comment: This is kind of old but just wanted to bump it and say that the original values are stock prices so it's not [0, 255]

Comment: I am having a huge error 10^6, so I normalized my acoustic data before feeding it into autoencoder. As a result my error reduce down to 1.89 with just normalizing it